# Paste a string of variable names into function in R

Tags: r, vector, rbind

I've got two strings of variable names that looks like this

```
> names_a = paste(paste0('a', seq(0,6,1)), collapse = ", ")
> names_a
[1] "a0, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6"
> names_b = paste(paste0('b', seq(0,6,1)), collapse = ", ")
> names_b
[1] "b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6"
```

Each`a` and `b` variable contains a vector of ids, for example:

```
> head(a3)
[1] "1234" "56567" "457659"...
```

I aim to get all possible pairs of `a` and `b` ids. For this purpose I try to paste variables' names rigth into function `rbind` and then to `expand.grid`

```
pairs = expand.grid(rbind(parse(text = names_a), rbind(parse(text = names_b))
```

I mean I try to collapse all `a0` to `a6` vectors into a single vector using `rbind`, let it be named `a`, the same for all `b`'s vectors and then find all pairs of values in `a` and `b`

surprisingly nothing works. Can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you post an example of the desired output?

Comment: I'm sorry for this messy question, it seems to be too complicated. This part of the code is extracted from a function that creats these vector a's and b's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
a1 = 1:2
a2 = 3:4
b1 = 5:6
b2 = 7:8
expand.grid(do.call(rbind, mget(paste("a", 1:2, sep = ""))),
         do.call(rbind, mget(paste("b", 1:2, sep = ""))))
#   Var1 Var2
#1     1    5
#2     3    5
#3     2    5
#4     4    5
#5     1    7
#6     3    7
#7     2    7
#8     4    7
#9     1    6
#10    3    6
#11    2    6
#12    4    6
#13    1    8
#14    3    8
#15    2    8
#16    4    8
```

Answer (score 2):

Collapse all of `a0` through `a6` into one vector:

```
a <- as.vector(sapply(strsplit(gsub(" ","",names_a),",")[[1]],function(x) get(x)))
```

(or if you don't have the names as a single string you need to parse):

```
a <- as.vector(sapply(paste0("a",0:6),function(x) get(x)))
```

Do the same with b and then

```
merge(a,b) #all pairs
```

This will generate duplicates if any of the a or b variables has duplicates, so you may want to add `unique` to the collapsing of a and b

Comment: I can't get it to work with vapply, but `unlist(lapply(paste0("b",0:6),function(x) get(x)))` also works